# Log4net : How to test UDP Appender quick

Tags: log4net

Just setup a UDP appender, and its not working, how can I very quickly check if messages are being sent outbound from the app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried monitoring them with a tool?

- [Log4net Viewer](http://devintelligence.com/Log4NetViewer/): With this tool you can recieve de udp-messages
- [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/): With this tool you can watch all the trafic on your network card and see if the messages are being send

Answer (score 1):

Really fast way for me was was [SocketSniff](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/socket_sniffer.html).

Answer (score 0):

Send one message at the start of the application at a level that will be logged. This way, you can be sure that it works at a specific point in time.

Answer (score 0):

You also can use Log2Console !